# Is it possible to import an excel sheet as a table in the database?

Tags: java, database, excel

This is the first time that I am attempting this, and I don't know if it is possible. I am trying to develop an application that allows me to upload an excel file directly into a database.

Is it possible to upload the excel data without first converting the excel sheet to the CSV format? The database table contains fields and columns with the same names as the excel file.

Does anyone know of a tool which can do this for me?

Comment: To what data base? all of the big BI tools are compatible with excel files.

Comment: If you want to map the columns directly there is a solution for MS-Access if we can consider Access as a database. If you want a proper DB you need to parse it.

Comment: I want in the proper database like sql or oracle. so i have to upload the excel through script..

Answer (score 3):

it is certainly possible. You might be interested in the [JBoss Teiid project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/TEIID/Home), which enables accessing Excel spreadsheet like it was a table.

Given that, you can then easily fill all the values from a "virtual" table formed from the spreadsheet (let's call it excelTable) into another table (let's call it targetTable):

```
INSERT INTO targetTable(column1,...) SELECT column1,... FROM excelTable;
```

The project is open-source so if its usage doesn't fit your needs, you can always look at the sources and maybe get an inspiration, how you can do such things.

Best regards

Jan

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, the easiest way is to use `sqlldr` for bulk load.

So you need an application that will parse the `xls/xlsx` and write a data file for `sqlldr` (can be `csv`, in fact any delimited text file).

If you really don't want to convert the file you could parse it and insert each row at a time, but this method is very slow when dealing with a lot of data.

[Sqlldr FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ)

**EDIT**: Equivalent tool for `sqlserver` is called `BCP`

[BCP Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

And of course, you can use the tools withouth any software attached, running them via command lines once you have the data and/or control files ready.